# Can't add audio for point sound effect in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

So here is my problem. I added two sound effects to my player for "Jumping" and "Dying" but when I try to add the "point" sound effect it just isnt working. What I am trying to accomplish is that when my player model goes through the middle of both pipes a sound effect will happen I am new so I am not sure why it isnt working and have no idea how to fix it.

here are some screenshots of Unity:
[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7axTh.png)
[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brf1C.png)

here is a youtube video showing the issue:
[video example](https://youtu.be/x_3Vj9MTbQ8)

here is the code for Smiley (player model)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SmileyScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;
    public float flapStrength;
    public logicScript logic;
    public PipeMiddleScript point;
    public bool birdIsAlive = true;
    public PipeMiddleScript pipeMiddle;

    [SerializeField] private AudioSource jumpSoundEffect;
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource deathSoundEffect;
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource pointSoundEffect;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        logic = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Logic").GetComponent<logicScript>();
        point = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Point").GetComponent<PipeMiddleScript>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) == true && birdIsAlive)
        {
            jumpSoundEffect.Play();
            myRigidbody.velocity = Vector2.up * flapStrength;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        deathSoundEffect.Play();
        logic.gameOver();
        birdIsAlive = false;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.layer == 3)
        {
            pointSoundEffect.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

here is the code for the middle of my pipe

[pipe middle](https://paste.myst.rs/2nar2dd7)

if you need any more information from me feel free to ask. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

I tried adding the audio effect to my player and programming it to where when I go through the pipe it will make a sound effect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that from your code, I can tell that you have put something in unity's layer 3. This is a problem because layer 3 is reserved for future utility use by unity. You can simply fix this by putting whatever you put in layer 3 in another layer, and checking collision with that layer. Please refrain from using layer 3 in the future.

Happy game development!

Comment: thank you for the knowledge about layer 3. I moved it to layer 6 but the problem still persists. I'm getting an error message now at the bottom of the screen that says "Tag: Point is not defined" I'm not sure what that means or how to fix it.

Comment: This error usually occurs when you try to check for a tag that you haven't made yet. I think what you did is you put "point" in the layer manager but not in the tag manager. Also, I do not see in your script where you need the 'point' object. Can I ask what its purpose is?

Comment: Also instead of using FindGameObjectWithTag every time you need to reference something, maybe just consider a simple 'GameObject.Find("gameobject name") or just use a serialized (or public) field, so that you do not have to make a new tag everytime you want to reference something.